# php mysql - Double rows of same data is being inserted on post to mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

This is the php script that i am running.Basically what i am trying to do is upload an image and a text onto mysql database using php,mysql and android.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    $image = $_POST['image'];
            $name = $_POST['name'];

    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $sql ="SELECT id FROM volleyupload ORDER BY id ASC";

    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $id = 0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            $id = $row['id'];
    }

    $path = "uploads/$id.png";

    $actualpath = "http://simplifiedcoding.16mb.com/PhotoUploadWithText/$path";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO volleyupload (photo,name) VALUES ('$actualpath','$name')";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
        echo "Successfully Uploaded";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. Please more obviously state the part that you need help with (e.g. what you expected some code to do that it did not do, or something your code did that you did not expect it to do).

Comment: Question i have: Does problem lie in script running twice or mysqli_query inserting double rows at once?

Comment: Do you have any triggers defined in the database? Are you sure that the form is only submitted once? Maybe you can post the code of that form? Is this piece of PHP code part of a bigger script that could be responsible for repetition? What you have provided so far does not explain double entries.

Comment: Note that with the INSERT statement it is normal you only keep inserting new records, even if it is for the same ID. Maybe you really want to use UPDATE ... WHERE ID = $id ?

Comment: @Sherif with this line  $sql = "INSERT INTO volleyupload (photo,name) VALUES ('$actualpath','$name')"; I am expecting it to have one entry into the database it is having two entries with different id's but with same data.eg:-id -1 http://104.197.53.207/webapp/10.jpeg anup and id -2 http://104.197.53.207/webapp/10.jpeg anup.

Comment: @anup Are you saying that each time you send the form two records immediately show up in your database with the same data, or that you're seeing multiple records with the same data? Because if it's the later than it's quite possible that you're just seeing duplicate records because you sent the form multiple times with the same file name. Clearly you code doesn't try to prevent duplicates records here, but the lack of database normalization merits its own question entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not want to use INSERT and that without specifying an ID.

I would replace this line:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO volleyupload (photo,name) VALUES ('$actualpath','$name')";
```

with something like:

```
$sql = "UPDATE volleyupload SET photo = '$actualpath', " .
    " name = '$name' WHERE id = $id";
```

It might need more work for the case where you did not find the id in the first query, because then you might want to INSERT anyway, but don't forget to then also insert a value for ID.